# Usage of swap partition in ec2 container service (AWS, Docker) really not possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I'm setting up a gitlab + redmine service for our startup company intern administration and code hosting using preconfigured Docker containers. Doing this was very easy using command line docker on a docker pre configured digitalocean image. It was even easer using tutum + digitalocean.

We think about using AWS for several purposes. So I tried setting up the mentioned configuration with EC2 Container Service (ECS). But on ECS, you have to allocate memory to each docker container. That means, containers can not share memory when they're running on the same server.

Even worse: Since you have to allocate memory to each container, your docker cannot use the servers swap, because swap cannot be allocated!

Why are these limitations in place? Is there a possible way to work around these?

Comment: Still not possible, and those issues mentioned above have been closed. I've opened a new issue: https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/771

Answer (score 1):

ATM its not possible to disable the OOM killer, nor over subscribe the underlying ram.

There are some feature requests on github that you can vote for:

- https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/155
- https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/124

Comment: Note that both issue are close. ECS now allows for soft memory limits (reservation). Use of swap memory is discussed here: https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/771